# why does my javascript code read a property of null on this json data?

Tags: javascript, json

EDIT: sorry, had the code ridden with errors. changed it now

Ive been trying to extract some JSON data from a github link to put it in a html file, but everytime I try to do so (with the code below), I get an Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property "value" of null. This even though "value" (in the Json file) certainly is not null.

What is going wrong here?

Thanks

you can check out the json file i put on github https://github.com/BearsAreFriendly/PolitiekeHelderheid/blob/master/kamerleden.json . I am quite certain that "value" has been defined

```
  var section = document.querySelector("section");
  var requestURL = 'https://github.com/BearsAreFriendly/PolitiekeHelderheid/blob/master/kamerleden.json';
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', requestURL);
  request.responseType = 'json';
  request.send();

  request.onload = function(){
    var phdata = request.response;
    showKamerleden(phdata);
  }
  function showKamerleden(jsonObj) {
  var kamerleden = jsonObj["value"];
  for (var i = 0; i < kamerleden.length; i++) {
      var myPara1 = document.createElement('p');
      myPara1.textContent = kamerleden[i].Id;
      section.appendChild(myPara1);
  }
  }
```

this should print out the id's. instead I get my mentioned error code

Comment: can you show us the response on the console.

Comment: The error means that `request.response` is null. Try using `JSON.parse(request.responseText)`

Comment: can you create a https://jsfiddle.net for this one, should not have been the issue with your jsonObj being null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may not actually be receiving any JSON data from GitHub, but HTML. When my browser requests a GitHub page the response content type is `Content-Type: text/html`. Your request URL should respond with JSON in order for it to be usable. When you request the GitHub URL you are likely getting other stuff (such as HTML), but not JSON.

For example, this url serves JSON data only: https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts

It has `Content-Type: application/json` when I inspect the page in dev tools under the network section

Modifying your code to add the url below works perfectly.

```js
var section = document.querySelector("section");
  var requestURL = 'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts';
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', requestURL);
  request.responseType = 'json';
  request.send();
  
  request.onload = function(){
    var phdata = request.response;
    /* showKamerleden(phdata); */
  document.write(JSON.stringify(phdata) ) 

  }
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var kamerledens = jsonObj.value;
```

instead of

```
var kamerledens = jsonObj["value"];
```

and also you should use a loop to go through all ids

```
function showKamerleden(jsonObj) {
var kamerledens = jsonObj.value;
for (var i = 0; i < kamerledens.length; i++) {
    var myPara1 = document.createElement('p');
    myPara1.textContent = kamerledens[i].Id;
    section.appendChild(myPara1);
}
}
```

Edited:

Try moving

```
  request.send();
```

after the `onload` function

Comment: hi, yeah thanks for correcting my mistake with the loop. this however still gives the error that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at showKamerleden
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onload`

Comment: @thelegend27 hi, check my new answer

Answer (score 0):

It isn't "value" that it is null, **jsonObj is null**.

Hence the error 'cannot read property "value" ***OF*** null'

I suggest you output and analyse the request in the callback

```
console.log(request)
```